# Summarising longitudinal data with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe which looks something like this:

```
set.seed(100)

library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(ID = rep(1:4, each = 2),
              weight = rep(abs(rnorm(4, 5, 3)), each = 2),
              year = rep(2013:2014, 4),
              var1 = sample(1:5, 8, rep = TRUE),
              var2 = sample(1:5, 8, rep = TRUE))
```

Producing data which looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 5
     ID   weight  year  var1  var2
  <int>    <dbl> <int> <int> <int>
1     1 3.493423  2013     3     2
2     1 3.493423  2014     1     2
3     2 5.394593  2013     4     2
4     2 5.394593  2014     5     4
5     3 4.763249  2013     2     3
6     3 4.763249  2014     2     4
7     4 7.660354  2013     4     3
8     4 7.660354  2014     4     4
```

I wish to make quick, simple inference on how things are changing from one year to the next. The ID variable is a unique identifier for each person in my longitudinal sample.

My idea would be to use `group_by(ID)` to group my data by by their ID, and then perhaps make use of the `summarise` function in some way. I desire the "collapse" effect we see when we use the `summarise` function.

For example, say I want to see if `var1` remains the same across the two years, by person. We see above this is true of persons 3 and 4. I would like to be able to obtain the following dataframe:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
     ID   weight indicator
  <int>    <dbl>     <lgl>
1     1 3.493423     FALSE
2     2 5.394593     FALSE
3     3 4.763249      TRUE
4     4 7.660354      TRUE
```

or, say I wanted to see the difference in `var2` from 2013 to 2014, I would desire the following dataframe:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
     ID   weight diff_var2
  <int>    <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1 3.493423         0
2     2 5.394593         2
3     3 4.763249         1
4     4 7.660354         1
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to go about this? I don't know how this would generalise to more years of data, but for the time being I am simply working with two years of longitudinal data.

Ultimately, for example, I would like to know the weighted proportion of people whose `var1` does not change, or the weighted mean movement in `var2` etc. These are just some examples of the sorts of queries I am looking into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've pretty much already laid out what you need to do, but group by both ID and weight if you want to save the columns.

```
df %>% group_by(ID, weight) %>% 
    summarise(indicator = n_distinct(var1) < n(), 
              diff_var2 = diff(var2))

## Source: local data frame [4 x 4]
## Groups: ID [?]
## 
##      ID   weight indicator diff_var2
##   <int>    <dbl>     <lgl>     <int>
## 1     1 3.493423     FALSE         0
## 2     2 5.394593     FALSE         2
## 3     3 4.763249      TRUE         1
## 4     4 7.660354      TRUE         1
```

If you have more than two years or missing data, you may need a more robust approach.

Comment: Brilliant - thankyou. `?summarise` does not give me a listing of these summary functions, is there a useful repository somewhere?

Comment: You can use any function that will return a vector of length one, regardless of its source, so it's not a finite list. `n` is a helper function from dplyr that gives the number of observations, like an `nrow` that respects grouping. `n_distinct` is a dplyr shortcut for the common `length(unique(...))`. `diff` is from the actual `base` package. All are documented in their respective packages.

Comment: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.5.0/topics/summarise offers a simple summary.  This is better: https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html This is best: https://www.datacamp.com/courses/dplyr-data-manipulation-r-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df)[, .(indicator=uniqueN(var1)==1, diff_var2= diff(var2)), ID]
 #   ID indicator diff_var2
 #1:  1     FALSE         0
 #2:  2     FALSE         2
 #3:  3      TRUE         1
 #4:  4      TRUE         1
```